# How to make file_get_contents recognize escape sequences as special characters?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, ansi-escape

I need to get content from a file so that the escape sequences (like \n) got recognized as special characters.

Consider the code:

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents("test.txt");
echo "$f";
?>
```

while test.txt contains only:

```
Test\nOnly
```

It echoes:

```
Test\nOnly
```

while I'd like to have:

```
Test
Only
```

Is there a way to accomplish it with file_get_content or should I use something else (like output buffering)?

Comment: its not the fault of file_get_contents, rather, where did you output your content.

Comment: Well, I'm running it as CLI script and intend to output it to terminal.

Comment: If it's displaying a literal `\n` then that's exactly what you have in your test.txt file.... create the file with a real linefeed in the first place

Comment: Alternatively, you'll have to str_replace() or preg_replace your `'\n'` to `"\n"` before echoing it

Comment: Nope, str_replace isn't an option because "\n" was only an example. A real line from included file could also be: "\e[1m-w\e[21m \e[4m<width>\e[24m"

Comment: If your file does contain VT escape sequences like that, then you'll need to parse it properly..... you can't expect PHP to do that automagically for you.... or make sure that they don't exists in the file in the first place

Comment: The latter. Seems I'd be best to use various HTML tags like <b></b> instead VT sequences and construct translation table. Then file_get_contents() and str_replace() tag=>VTseq one by one.

Comment: Still, if there is simpler method, I'll be glad to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

try using `printf` which the function outputs a formatted string.

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents("test.txt");
printf ($f);
?>
```

Comment: Nope. Syntax is: printf( format, var...) and "%s" format has nothing to do with such double-quotes escape sequences interpretation.